# Pandas multindex DataFrame: replace certain values by values from other column on 2nd level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I've got the following multiindex DataFrame:

```
    0   M1        M2     
  bla    C   LQ    C   LQ
0   1  1.6  0.1  2.7  0.5
1   2  <LQ  0.2  4.1  0.3
2   3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   4  3.2  0.1  <LQ  0.4
```

Furthermore I created a mask of where `'C'` is `"<LQ"`, dropping the 2nd level

```
mask = df.xs('C',level=1, axis=1) == "<LQ"
```

I'd like to

1. replace `'<LQ'` by the value in the respective `'LQ'` column
2. drop the `'LQ'` colums and reduce the columns to one level, keeping the name of the first level where the second level is `['C', 'LQ']` and keeping the name of the second level for the rest like this:

:

```
   bla     M1    M2
0    1    1.6   2.7
1    2    0.2   4.1
2    3    NaN   NaN
3    4    3.2   0.4
```

while keeping track of the replaced values using the mask (eg. for later plotting)

Code to generate the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({(0,'bla'): [1,2,3,4],
                   ('M1', 'C'): [1.6,'<LQ',np.nan,3.2],
                   ('M1', 'LQ'): [0.1,0.2,np.nan,0.1],
                   ('M2', 'C'): [2.7,4.1,np.nan,'<LQ'],
                   ('M2', 'LQ'): [0.5,0.3,np.nan,0.4]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use[`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace values with `<LQ` by `LQ` DataFrame, then remove this levels by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with removing first level of `MultiIndex` by [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together:

```
df1 = df.xs('C',level=1, axis=1)
df1 = df1.mask(df1 == "<LQ", df.xs('LQ',level=1, axis=1))

df2 = df.drop(['C','LQ'], axis=1, level=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)

df = df2.join(df1)
print (df)
   bla   M1   M2
0    1  1.6  2.7
1    2  0.2  4.1
2    3  NaN  NaN
3    4  3.2  0.4
```

If only one `0, bla` column then use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index((0,'bla'))
df1 = df.xs('C',level=1, axis=1)
df = (df1.mask(df1 == "<LQ", df.xs('LQ',level=1, axis=1))
         .rename_axis('bla')
         .reset_index())

print (df)
   bla   M1   M2
0    1  1.6  2.7
1    2  0.2  4.1
2    3  NaN  NaN
3    4  3.2  0.4
```